# background worker dont work

Tags: background, worker

I want to read a text file from the Internet and I want while reading the file a picturebox, that is a gif animation, show and after the reading is finished picturebox hide.
I use background worker. I have a lable that shows the state, but when I click `BtnCheck` Button bg doesn't work and the lable doesn't change.

My code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }
    private void BtnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PbLoading.Visible = true;
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        LbleState.Text = "Reading txt File...";
        webClient1 = new WebClient();
        if (CheckForInternetConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                Stream stream = webClient1.OpenRead(TxtWebAdrss);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                LbleState.Text = "Reading Finished .";
            }
            catch
            {
                LbleState.Text = "Error reading";
            }


        }
        else LbleState.Text = "Internet not connected!";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to do a bit more research into this class. You should perform UI changes on the UI thread.

There are three event handlers that you can use and these are,

```
backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
```

The following link should help,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker(v=vs.110).aspx